# How replace the text inside a csv using regex in groovy/gradle?

Tags: regex, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am writing a Gradle task that should open a text file & make some edits in the content.

Below is the task I have written so far

```
task editFile {
    ant.replaceregexp(match:'DIR/javalib/my-old-jar-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar', 
        replace:'DIR/javalib/my-new-jar-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar') {
            fileset(dir: 'bootstrap/csv_folder', includes: 'mycsv.csv')
    }
}
```

I am looking for a regex something like `'^DIR/javalib/.*jar$'` to locate the

```
'my-old-jar-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

portion of the text. I am totally new to regex & groovy, hence go easy on me.

Comment: as soon as you are using `ant.replaceregexp` - why not to open [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) and check for examples? or edit your questions and add more details: file example, what have you tried, what is the exact problem... btw. it's possible to use [ant expand properties filter](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#expandproperties)

Comment: @daggett I am quite new to the regex & gradle, hence the question. If I provide full name as matcher, the replacement works fine. But If I try using wild cards like '*', '%', '?', it does nothing. I just can't get my head around the regex. Hope you understand.

Comment: edit your questions and provide example of your csv file content, specify what you try to replace, and your code... btw there are online regex helpers like: https://regexr.com/

Comment: @daggett I have updated the question with more details. I did check out https://regexr.com/, but since I am totally new to regex it is not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
task editFile {
    ant.replaceregexp(match:'DIR/javalib/.*jar', 
        replace:'DIR/javalib/my-new-jar-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar') {
            fileset(dir: 'bootstrap/csv_folder', includes: 'mycsv.csv')
    }
}
```

Modifying the task as above, I was able to accomplish the task.